# Setter not throwing errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, typeerror, setter

I have a `Node` class that I'd like to make sure only accepts other `Node` object as its child, but the `TypeError` is never raised in my unit tests. I'm using python 3.

#### Class

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._child = None
        self._data = data

    @property
    def child(self):
        return self._child

    @child.setter
    def child(self, child):
        if not isinstance(child, Node):
            raise TypeError(f"Children must be of type Node, not {type(child)}.")
        self._child = child

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, data):
        self._data = data
```

#### Test

```py
def test_node_child_error():
    node = Node(1)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        node.child = 2
```

The unit test returns `Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'TypeError'>` and when I try and log the new value to the terminal inside of the setter it says that `child` is `<class 'NoneType'>`, but the value does change according to the `Node` object itself when I log it afterwards.

I have been trying to use the PyCharm debugger to get a closer look, but unfortunately I used the same class name in another file as a class used in the debugger so it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The test is working on my machine. I spotted 2 things in your code, you may try fix them and try again. In the `child` setter there is a variable called `right` that is not defined and there is a space between `self.` and `_child` (the test works for me regardless).

How are you running the tests? I did it by executing: `pytest`

Comment: `right` should obviously be `child`.

Comment: Those were just typos copying over my code. Thanks for pointing that out, they are correct in my code and the test still doesn't work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure you have `self._child = None` in `__init__`, and not `self.child = None`?

Comment: (Arguably, `self._child = None` is wrong, though. The point of the setter is to ensure `self._child` doesn't receive an invalid value, and you are circumventing that by not using the setter in `__init__`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue but would appreciate some explanation as to why/how this fixes it. Obviously the issue was coming from the setter getting a `None` type every time it is called so I edited the setter to be as follows.

```py
@child.setter
def child(self, child):
    if not isinstance(child, Node) and child is not None:
        raise TypeError(f"Children must be of type Node, not {type(child)}.")
    self._child = child
```

Not only does this fix my test cases, but now when I try to purposely throw the error I get the correct error message of `TypeError: Children must be of type Node, not <class 'int'>.` instead of `TypeError: Children must be of type Node, not <class 'None'>.`.

Comment: See my comment on the question. This is, however, a correct setter if the intended type of the `_child` attribute is `Optional[Node]` rather than `Node`.